# Check null value in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

In SQL Server we can use IsNull() function to check whether expression value is null or not. For ex.

```
Select IsNull(sum(amount),0) as TotalAmount
  From Payments
```

Likewise is there any function in MS Access Query to check the null? I need the same statement to be executed in MS Access Query.

Can anybody tell me the replacement for `IsNull()` in MS Access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much the equivalent in Access is the **nz** function.

There's a good page on how to use it [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).

However, if you're using Access just as a database backend and using Jet in your connectionstring then nz won't be available to you.

Comment: Thanks hawbsl!  But when i try to execute query using Nz from C# code, i get exception that Nz is not defined.

Comment: I found IsNull() is present within MS Access. But when using the query from c#, i m getting this error message - "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'IsNull(sum(amount),0)'"

Comment: Unfortunately if you're accessing the Access database through C# then you're using Jet rather than Access itself. Different rules apply and there are various useful functions which aren't available to you.

Comment: well, one way is to handle nulls in C# in your front end. sure that's no help if you're trying to use isnull inside a join but it doesn't look like you're trying to do that.

Answer (score 10):

Using Jet/ACE your query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT IIf(Sum(amount) Is Null, 0, Sum(amount)) AS TotalAmount
FROM Payments
```

This should work even from C# because `Is Null` and `IIf` are both built in to Jet/ACE.  Please note the space in `Is Null` and the lack of parentheses (it is a *statement*, not a *function*).

There are two added bonuses to using `IIf` and `Is Null` as opposed to `Nz` even if `Nz` is available to you:

- it executes faster because all the processing is done within the database engine (so it doesn't have to make function calls to the Access library)
- it retains the field's original type; because `Nz` returns a Variant, Jet/ACE is forced to display the result as a string (which is usually not what you want when dealing with dates, numerics, etc)

**UPDATE**:  Allen Browne has an [***excellent primer***](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html) on the use of `IIf`, `Nz`, `IsNull()`, and `Is Null`.  I was planning on posting that link as my original answer, but I couldn't find the page at the time.  I did the best I could from memory, but the true credit goes to Mr. Browne.

Comment: Is the Jet/ACE version of IsNull() available here? I worry that the SQL Is Null is doing something different. I also wonder about using it on the Sum() instead of on the Amount field.

Comment: Yeah, without testing I'm not sure how Jet/ACE would handle summing with Nulls.  It seems like, from a performance standpoint, if Jet/ACE treats Nulls as 0 for summing purposes, then it would be more efficient to check for Null once at the end instead of for each record.

Comment: I just ran a quick check and Sum() appears to treat Nulls as 0.  I'd have to actually benchmark it to see if it made any difference performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise ,
can also be used on date and time when sorting

```
.....ORDER BY TRANSDATE ASC,(IIf([PaymentTime] Is Null, '23:59:59', [PaymentTime])) DESC
```