# How would I join a value of zero when a left join doesn't match?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm looking to join the field Count from the query qCallCount to the results of the query qCustomers. I think I want to use a left join because there are customers in the qCustomers dataset that won't have a match in the qCallCount dataset, but I don't want to drop them from the results.

My current query...

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, b.Count, a.Customer_Segmentation
FROM qCustomers AS a LEFT JOIN qCallCount AS b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID;
```

My question is, is there a way to make the value for the Count field in the result of this query have a value of 0 if there's no match in qCallCount?
If this was Excel I'd write an =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CustomerID, qCallCount, Count, False),0)

Why do I need this? I'm ultimately going to run an average of count `avg(Count) as Average` and it's important for those failed matches to be treated as zero, because that's what they actually are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB/VBA/MS Access null-coalescing function is `Nz`. (In VB6, `IsNull` is not the same as in SQL Server--it's a different function that returns a Boolean indicating whether the value is Null.) So it would look like this:

```
SELECT
   a.CustomerID,
   Nz(b.Count, 0) AS CallCount,
   a.Customer_Segmentation
FROM
   qCustomers AS a
   LEFT JOIN qCallCount AS b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check null value in MS Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828021/check-null-value-in-ms-access-query)

You can check for IsNull(b.Count, 0)

Is Count the name of a column, or are you using the function Count?

Comment: Count is the name of the column.

Comment: @nshah You should post this as an answer. Nice finding.

Comment: Thank you Nshah.  I created ErikE's answer (which was correct) before he did because of you answer and follow up comment.